# What is the best way to use a common vector size type?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, vector

When creating a templated vector class, what is the best way to allow use its size type? From what I have gathered, it seems as if it is to make an interface to the real vector class, then use that. Such as

```
for(VectorBase::size_type i = 0; i < test1.size(); ++i)
```

This has the advantage over

```
for(Vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < test1.size(); ++i)
```

for making code cleaner and not having to know the Vector's templated type (in case it changes).

For an example of my implementation (in case there is a better way, here is how I created it).

```
class VectorBase
{
public:
    typedef unsigned int size_type;

protected:
    size_type mCount;

public:
    VectorBase() { mCount = 2; } 
    virtual ~VectorBase() = 0 { }
    size_type size() const { return mCount; }
};

template<typename Type>
class Vector : public VectorBase
{
public:
    Vector() : VectorBase() { }
    ~Vector() { }
};

int main(void)
{
    Vector<int> test1;

    for(VectorBase::size_type i = 0; i < test1.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return(0);
}
```

(Note: Please do not turn this into a "Just use xxx vector class.").

Comment: What happens if find out that you want your `size_type` to depend on your template arguments?

Comment: I'd prefer access via iterators over indexed access - it's more general and flexible, unless the actual index value itself has some meaning.

Comment: @ Grizzly, I am not concerned over my size_type coming from a template argument. It will always be the same.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB, I agree that is most cases that iterators should be used. This was to demonstrate a way that size_type would be used, and was wondering on the best way it should be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not having to know the Vector's templated type (in case it changes).

If you're worried about the container type changing, either:

1. Create a typedef for it, so `test1` is declared using the same type name that you use in the loop, but the type represented by that name can change in future.
2. Write proper generic functions, so the type of the container is a template parameter `T` or whatever, and you use `typename T::size_type` as the type of `i`. Then if the type changes, your code copes.

Example of (1):

```
typedef vector<int> test_type;
test_type test1;
// populate the vector
for (test_type::size_type i = 0; i < test1.size(); ++i) std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Example of (2):

```
template <typename Container>
void print_indexes(const Container &test1) {
    for (typename Container::size_type i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Alternative workarounds:

1) Just use `std::size_t`. Slightly cheating, since in principle I suppose a `vector<bool>` can have more than `SIZE_MAX` elements, but no "proper" vector can get bigger than that.

2) (C++11 only) use `auto` as the type of `i`

```
for (auto i = test.size(); i != 0; --i) std::cout << (test.size() - i) << '\n';
```

or

```
for (decltype(test.size()) i = 0; i < test1.size(); ++i) ...
```

Personally I'd follow the style used in the standard libraries, and not bother with a common base class for a container class template.

Comment: Another person mentioned your second point, which I am interested in. If I were to remove VectorBase, then have the template be "template<typename Type, typename SizeType = unsigned int>", how could I expose the type easily to the user?

Comment: @mmurphy: usually something like `template<typename Type, typename SizeType = unsigned int> class myvector { public: typedef Type value_type; typedef SizeType size_type; };`.

Comment: How can I easily access the size_type value then? It would seem like I would need to do something like "Vector<int>::size_type" (when my type is int), which was partially my concern, though it may be the only way it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is best way.  :-)

By moving some parts to a common base class you simplify the interface, but you also take away some of the choices for the derived classes or specializations of your template.

For example, a `vector<char>` might need a `long long` size type if you want it to hold a very large number of characters. A potential specialization for `vector<my_huge_type>` perhaps only needs an `int`?

Should we decide up front that unsigned int is always good enough? Maybe, maybe not. Designing an interface if often to find a good balance between complexity and flexibility.

Comment: You bring up a very good point. So if I were to remove VectorBase, then have the template be "template<typename Type, typename SizeType = unsigned int>", how could I expose the type easily to the user?

Comment: The std::vector has a typedef (without having the type being a template parameter). That allows specializations to have a different typedef, should they ever want to (unlikely :-). By making it a template parameter you allow `Vector<char, int>` and `Vector<char, long>` which seems like *too much* flexibility. :-)

Comment: @Bo: signed size types are definitely too much flexibility!

Comment: I highly doubt there is, but is there way to have only unsigned sizes?

Comment: I used signed types just to show that it *is* an option to have size_type the same as ptrdiff_t. The standard containers don't have that partly because that would limit a vector<char> to "only" half the address space, and partly because the standards committee has no consensus on what is *really* the best choice.

Comment: @mmurphy: You can static assert that `!std::numeric_limits<SizeType>::is_signed`. @Bo: container `size_type`s are required to be unsigned ([container.requirements]), sounds like a consensus to me even if some people are quietly unhappy about it ;-) Obviously your own classes can give the name `size_type` to anything they like, but if it's signed then it's not a container.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to rewrite Vector when there is already a perfectly good one?

If you did have to inherit from VectorBase though it would be better to give VectorBase a protected destructor rather than a public virtual one, as now you have given Vector a v-table.

Incidentally the syntax of your pure virtual destructor is not standard.

There is no compiler overhead (i.e. bloat) in keeping the typedef of size_type in each vector template so there would have been no great advantage in moving it.

Comment: @ CashCow, my last line was "(Note: Please do not turn this into a "Just use xxx vector class.")." How is my pure virtual destructor not standard?

Comment: It is not permitted in the standard to follow = 0 with {} although some compilers will allow it.

Comment: How should it be then, {} = 0?